# How efficient is the collection.sort() function?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, sorting

How fast is the collection.sort() function in Java? What algorithm was used? I came across this function [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16252270/369) that sorts a list in descending order:

```
public static void main(String arg[])
{
    List<Double> testList=new ArrayList();

   /*Adding The values to the List*/

    testList.add(0.5);
    testList.add(0.2);
    testList.add(0.9);
    testList.add(0.1);
    testList.add(0.1);
    testList.add(0.1);
    testList.add(0.54);
    testList.add(0.71);
    testList.add(0.71);
    testList.add(0.71);
    testList.add(0.92);
    testList.add(0.12);
    testList.add(0.65);
    testList.add(0.34);
    testList.add(0.62);

    /*Declare a new List for storing sorted Results*/

    List<Double> finalList=new ArrayList();


    while(!testList.isEmpty()) //perform operation until all elements are moved to new List
    {
        double rank=0;
        int i=0;
            for(double d: testList)
            {
                if(d>=rank)
                {
                    rank=d;
                }

            }
            finalList.add(rank);

            testList.remove(testList.indexOf(rank));

     }
    for(double d : finalList) {
        System.out.println(d);
    }

}
```

I think this runs in O(n(n-1)) time and it would be pretty inefficient for a large list. I don't believe this is how Collections.sort() was created considering how inefficient it is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the Documentation on Collection's method sort():

> Implementation note: **This implementation is a stable, adaptive, iterative `mergesort` that requires far fewer than n lg(n) comparisons when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the performance of a traditional mergesort when the input array is randomly ordered.** If the input array is nearly sorted, the implementation requires approximately n comparisons. Temporary storage requirements vary from a small constant for nearly sorted input arrays to n/2 object references for randomly ordered input arrays.

It means that is **O(n log n)** in the **worst case**. So YES it's very fast (even in the worst case), much faster than a O(n^2) sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

To quote [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)):

> Implementation note: This implementation is a stable, adaptive, iterative mergesort that requires far fewer than n lg(n) comparisons when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the performance of a traditional mergesort when the input array is randomly ordered. If the input array is nearly sorted, the implementation requires approximately n comparisons. Temporary storage requirements vary from a small constant for nearly sorted input arrays to n/2 object references for randomly ordered input arrays.
>
> The implementation takes equal advantage of ascending and descending order in its input array, and can take advantage of ascending and descending order in different parts of the same input array. It is well-suited to merging two or more sorted arrays: simply concatenate the arrays and sort the resulting array.
>
> The implementation was adapted from Tim Peters's list sort for Python ( TimSort). It uses techiques from Peter McIlroy's "Optimistic Sorting and Information Theoretic Complexity", in Proceedings of the Fourth Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms, pp 467-474, January 1993.
>
> This implementation dumps the specified list into an array, sorts the array, and iterates over the list resetting each element from the corresponding position in the array. This avoids the n2 log(n) performance that would result from attempting to sort a linked list in place.